# Can't deploy UWP app to any mobile emulator with latest Visual Studio and emulators

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

Relevant Visual Studio Version Information -

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00079
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA127 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-20000-00000-AA127 Windows Phone
>   SDK 8.0 - ENU

Microsoft Emulator version installed 10.0.26624
Although in the Device Selector in Visual Studio it says 10.0.1024.0.

If I create a new UWP (Windows Universal App) and try to deploy it to any mobile emulator is fails with

> "There were deployment errors. Continue?"

Investigating the output window and error list there is absolutely nothing there.

I can deploy the application when the target is Local Machine.

Hyper V has no virtual machines registered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the information you get "Hyper V has no virtual machines registered" suggest that your Hyper-V is disabled. 
Try to type in coreinfo-v.exe in your cmd to find out.
Make sure that your processor supports Virtualization otherwise there is nothing you can do.:(
If you follow this link you will find quite a lot of information how to enable Hyper-V in your computer. 
It's an article for Windows phone emulator 8.1 but still quite useful. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx#coreinfo